# Kubernetes service with type=LoadBalancer, how does update to the service happen

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I was checking UpdateLoadBalancer implementation in kubernetes. Following is my understanding:

Setup – 3 nodes – 1 Master and 2 Minions

- Create a service with type=LoadBalancer, without any pods associated to it.
- Create 1 pod(pod-1 lands in minion-1) for the service – UpdateLoadBalancer is 
  invoked.
- Scale the pods for the service to 2.

  - Pod-2 lands in minion-2 - UpdateLoadBalancer is invoked.
  - Scale the pods to 3. Pod-3 lands in minion-1 or minion-2 - 
    UpdateLoadBalancer is not invoked.

The reason is, UpdateLoadBalancer is only called if a new minion/node is associated with a service. Since minion-1 and minion-2 are already associated with the service, update is not invoked.

I am writing a cloud provider plugin for kubernetes. Currently all the cloud providers have added minion nodes as members for load balancer. But in my implementation I have added the pod's IP as members of the LB.

From my understanding, I think that update is not possible with the current design. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This might be a good question to ask on `kubernetes-dev` mailing list.

Comment: Thanks!! Just posted the question on kubernetes-dev mailing list.